# Swift Visual Format Language Not working

Tags: swift, visual-format-language

I'm trying to get the Visual Format Language working in swift but I just can't get it to work with a simple example. I'm trying to get the label to show up somewhere else other than the top left corner. This is how it shows up now:

[image: Test]

And this is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label 1"
        label.sizeToFit()

        self.view.addSubview(label)
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("label", label))

        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-30-[label]-|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)

        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-30-[label]-|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)

        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
}
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: Try adding `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` so that label has this option disabled to. Do you get any runtime log saying some constraints are not satisfiable ?

Comment: @tomahh That did it! Add it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Without this, the label's autoresizing mask is transformed into constraints when `layoutSubviews` is performed. The boolean applies only to the view and not its subviews.